# Resolving this aligning problem?

Tags: math-mode, align

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\nabla \varphi (r, \theta) 
&= \nabla f(x, y)\cdot Dg(r, \theta)\\
&= \nabla f(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)\cdot Dg(r, \theta)\\
&= \Big( D_{1}f(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta), D_{2}f(r\cos \theta, r\sin       
\theta) \Big)\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -r\sin \theta\\
\sin \theta & r\cos \theta
\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \Big( 
D_{1}f(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)\cos \theta + D_{2}f(r\cos \theta,    
r\sin \theta)\sin \theta,
-D_{1}f(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)r\sin \theta + D_{2}f(r\cos \theta,     
r\sin \theta)r\cos \theta 
\Big).
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

The problem is that the pair on the right-hand side (enclosed by `\Big(` and `\Big)`) of the last equality is too long to be shown properly. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

With the `multlined` environment (from `mathtools`) it is automated:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \nabla \varphi (r, \theta)
              & = \nabla f(x, y)\cdot Dg(r, \theta) \\
              & = \nabla f(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)\cdot Dg(r, \theta) \\
              & = \Big( D_{1}f(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta), D_{2}f(r\cos \theta, r\sin
  \theta) \Big)\cdot
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos \theta & -r\sin \theta \\
  \sin \theta & r\cos \theta
  \end{bmatrix}\\
              & = \!\begin{multlined}[t]\Big(
  D_{1}f(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)\cos \theta + D_{2}f(r\cos \theta,
  r\sin \theta)\sin \theta,\\
  -D_{1}f(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)r\sin \theta + D_{2}f(r\cos \theta,
  r\sin \theta)r\cos \theta
  \Big).
  \end{multlined}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something as easy as to break the line before in a point where you consider is correct with `\\` could help you. The following part of the trick is to add a new row with the remaining part of the equation.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\nabla \varphi (r, \theta) 
&= \nabla f(x, y)\cdot Dg(r, \theta)\\
&= \nabla f(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)\cdot Dg(r, \theta)\\
&= \Big( D_{1}f(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta), D_{2}f(r\cos \theta, r\sin       
\theta) \Big)\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -r\sin \theta\\
\sin \theta & r\cos \theta
\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \Big( 
D_{1}f(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)\cos \theta + D_{2}f(r\cos \theta,    
r\sin \theta)\sin \theta,
-D_{1}f(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)r\sin \theta + D_{2}f\\
& \qquad (r\cos \theta,     
r\sin \theta)r\cos \theta 
\Big).
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

As you can see I added a `\qquad` macro before for fix the alignment. Maybe isn't the most elegant solution, but you can try it.

Comment: Thank you. I heard of \qquad but am not familiar with it. Yes, it works perfectly

Comment: `\qquad` is simply a macro that add horizontal space inside a line. The size is of a double em space, a common typographical length measure unit. Originally was named [quadrat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad_%28typography%29) and is the widest horizontal space you can achieve in LaTeX. There are also another spaces such as `\quad`(only an em space) `\;`(5/18 of an em), `\:` (4/18 of an em), `\,` (3/18 of an em) and `\!` (-3/18 of an em, it's negative space).